# Step Wizard Form in C# application

Tags: c#, winforms

as you have seen before we have asp.net wizard componant for web application Is there any simple componant that implements this method for windows application using c# language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ak_wizard.aspx) looks like a fairly decent implementation of one on CodeProject. The best bit about it is it's free :-)

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress makes an [XtraWizard](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Wizard/) control.
Note that it's not free.

Comment: Yes it is nice but I want something free, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's not any built-in but here it is one on [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/DesignTimeWizard.aspx):